# Mapear un objeto por JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Estoy mapeando un objeto desde mi controller, lo envio atravez del metodo GET por JSON. El objeto lo genera bien, revise que traiga datos. La comunicacion es correcta, funciona bien si le envio un objeto vacio o un texto, el problema es cuando lo envia a JSON. Me tira error, cuando quiero ver la descripcion del objeto dice "[Object object]" y cuando quiero ver sus valores "Undefined".

A que puede deberse el error? Estoy usando de Model un ViewModel que no tiene a dicha clase, podra ser ese el problema? Lo que me llama la atencion es que me funcionaba perfecto el envio de datos, pero cuando cambie la implementacion de la base de datos (use Entity Framework) ahora me devuelve error en lugar de mapearlo correctamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya descubri lo que era: como habia usado entity framework me marcaba las dependencias como atributos del modelo, entonces, al querer crear un nuevo objeto de dicho modelo, me tiraba error por que no encontraba las dependencias en json. Igual por las dudas instale Newton Json